# Remove dates in a row before specific date and move next date to forward in row in pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics, exploratory-data-analysis

Given Data:

```
|   Id     | start Date     | Frequency | Date1       | Dat2        | Date3       | Date4       |Date5        |
| -------- | -------------- | --------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1        | 10-10-2014     |     1     | 10-10-2015  | 10-10-2016  | 10-10-2017  | 10-10-2018  | 10-10-2019  |
| 2        | 20–10-2015     |     2     | 20-04-2016  | 20-10-2016  | 20-04-2017  | 20-10-2017  | 20-14-2018  |
```

Required Dataset

```
|   Id     | start Date     | Frequency | Date1       | Dat2        | Date3       | Date4       |Date5        |
| -------- | -------------- | --------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1        | 10-10-2014     |     1     | 10-10-2016  | 10-10-2017  | 10-10-2018  | 10-10-2019  |             |
| 2        | 20–10-2015     |     2     | 20-10-2016  | 20-04-2017  | 20-10-2017  | 20-14-2018  |             |
```

Dates before October 2016 need to be removed and next will fill removed dates cells.

My code is time-consuming on 2,00,000 rows is there an easy method?

```
for i in range(0,len(f1)) :
    ff0=f1.loc[f1_index[i]].tolist()
    dt1= pd. DataFrame (ff0)
    dft1 = dt1[~(dt1[0]<' 2015-01-01' )]
    dtL1= dft1[0]. tolist()
    a_series1= pd. Series (dtL1, index= f1. columns[0:len(dtL1)])
    F2=F2.append (a_seriesl, ignore index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, with the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "start Date": [
            "10-10-2014",
            "20-10-2015",
            "21-10-2015",
            "21-10-2015",
            "21-10-2015",
        ],
        "Frequency": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "Date1": ["10-10-2015", "20-04-2016", "21-11-2016", "20-04-2016", "21-12-2017"],
        "Date2": ["10-10-2016", "20-10-2016", "21-10-2016", "20-10-2016", "20-10-2016"],
        "Date3": ["10-10-2017", "20-04-2017", "21-04-2017", "20-04-2017", "20-04-2017"],
        "Date4": ["10-10-2018", "20-10-2017", "21-10-2017", "20-10-2017", "20-10-2017"],
        "Date5": ["10-10-2019", "20-14-2018", "21-14-2018", "20-14-2018", "20-14-2018"],
    }
)
```

You could try using [Pandas shift method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), like this:

```py
df["Date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date1"], format="%d-%m-%Y")

index = df[df["Date1"] < pd.Timestamp(year=2016, month=10, day=1)].index.tolist()

df.loc[index, ["Date1", "Date2", "Date3", "Date4", "Date5"]] = df.loc[
    index, ["Date1", "Date2", "Date3", "Date4", "Date5"]
].shift(-1, axis=1)

print(df)
# Output
   Id  start Date  Frequency      Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4       Date5
0   1  10-10-2014          1 2016-10-10  10-10-2017  10-10-2018  10-10-2019         NaN
1   2  20-10-2015          2 2016-10-20  20-04-2017  20-10-2017  20-14-2018         NaN
2   3  21-10-2015          3 2016-11-21  21-10-2016  21-04-2017  21-10-2017  21-14-2018
3   4  21-10-2015          4 2016-10-20  20-04-2017  20-10-2017  20-14-2018         NaN
4   5  21-10-2015          5 2017-12-21  20-10-2016  20-04-2017  20-10-2017  20-14-2018
```